# Jenkins environment variables available during post build step

Tags: jenkins

I understand that Jenkins sets certain environment variables during build execution. But my question is can I access those variables in my post-build script ?

I ran a quick test and I am unable to access PROJECT_NAME and BUILD_URL etc from a post build step python script.

Is there a way I can access these variables from a post build step python script ? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another solution is to use the [Jenkins EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to redefine the Jenkins parameters as environment variables:

[image]

This environment variable should be available in your post build step Python script.

On Linux and with a Shell script, I'm able to access both (Jenkins parameters and environment variables):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

EnvInject plugin reads a properties file each time I need to export a variable.

So I implemented the needed functionality using Groovy PostBuild plugin in the first post-build step which reads all needed variables from a properties file and exports them for the next post-build steps:

```
/*
Inject environment variables using Groovy because EnvInject plugin is not user-friendly
*/

import hudson.model.*

def console = manager.listener.logger.&println

// read the props file
def props = new Properties()
new File("${manager.envVars['WORKSPACE']}/postbuild.props").withInputStream { 
    stream -> props.load(stream) 
}

props.each{
    key, value -> console("${key}:${value}")
    def pa = new ParametersAction([
        new StringParameterValue(key, value)
    ])
    manager.build.addAction(pa)
}
```

And on each build step which needs to pass variables to post-build steps I do something like:

```
echo "hipchat_message=Server build succeded: <a href='https://$SERVER_NAME/'>$SERVER_NAME</a> (<a href='$BUILD_URL'>Job</a>)" > "$WORKSPACE/postbuild.props"
```

Comment: this looks like exactly what I need... I see the values read correctly and logged to console, but the injected value does not seem to be available in subsequent post-build steps (e.g. Slack notification)

Comment: I found the answer... in later Jenkins (2.x >) there is some security restriction, you have to add a line `System.setProperty("hudson.model.ParametersAction.safeParameters", "BUILD_URL")` in your groovy script for each env var you want to set. See here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35377?focusedCommentId=261159#comment-261159

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about python but at least shell scripts can take parameters from Jenkins

```
/code/workspace/myscript.sh ${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

You just need to add it to the post steps

[image: Jenkins post step screen]

Comment: I didn't try this, but I came across an open issue with passing arguments, so I am guessing this won't work. See: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19873

Answer (score 0):

Yes, environment variables that are generated **by Jenkins itself** are available in post-build steps (for your own environment variables, you will need [**EnvInject plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin))

You can run post-build "execute shell" or "execute batch command" step and just type `set`. Everything you see there is accessible.

Comment: Is true for maven projects, but not true for freestyle projects

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a Freestyle project, too. I solved it now by moving the post build step into the build part itself (as last step there).